# md-nav-list set default selected item from *ngFor list

Tags: angular-material2

```
<md-nav-list>
    <md-list-item *ngFor="let distributionGroup of distributionGroupIndexes$ | async;" 
    (click)=selectDistributionGroup(distributionGroup.id)>
        <span>{{distributionGroup.name}}</span>
    </md-list-item>
</md-nav-list>
```

In the example above I would like to be able to specify the initially selected `md-list-item`. I cant seem to find a way of doing this.

The list is being populated asychronously (notice the `| async`) but I dont think that is the source of my trouble...

I have found references to md-selected-item for other material elements, so optimistically attempted adding 
`md-selected-item="distributionGroupIndexes$[0] | async"` to md-nav-list, but no joy.

Any hints as to how this should be done would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You may of solved this by now bu this could help someone else, I binded the selection to a data model from the view to the component.ts.

```
 <md-list-item *ngFor="let distributionGroup of distributionGroupIndexes$ | async;" 
(click)=selectDistributionGroup(distributionGroup.id)>
```

add this within the tag:

```
[(ngModel)="distributionGroup.id"]
```

then give it default value in the component, the view will load with this value selected.